# SQL Query Running super slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

The code I'm running below runs really quite fine, until I try and fetch the Quantity in the last loop. I think it could probably be optimized with JOINs etc but I'm not overly familiar with the best approach for this when grabbing DISTINCT elements?

```
$sql_dept = "SELECT DISTINCT `department_guid` FROM `bom_material_copy` WHERE `complex_guid`='9EB75BE9-26E2-AEBB-1B52-37DBC2FB89EA' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,5";

foreach($pdo->query($sql_dept) AS $dept)
{
    $sql_mat = "SELECT DISTINCT `material_bct_number` FROM `bom_material_copy` WHERE 
                `complex_guid`='9EB75BE9-26E2-AEBB-1B52-37DBC2FB89EA' AND 
                `department_guid`='".$dept['department_guid']."' 
                ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,5";

    foreach($pdo->query($sql_mat) AS $mat)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$mat['material_bct_number']."</td>";
            // Grab Units Again
            $u = 0;
            $sql_unit = "SELECT DISTINCT `unit_number` FROM `bom_projects_units` WHERE `complex_guid`='9EB75BE9-26E2-AEBB-1B52-37DBC2FB89EA'";
            foreach($pdo->query($sql_unit) AS $unit)
            {
                $sql_quan = "SELECT `quantity` FROM `bom_material_copy` 
                            WHERE 
                            `material_bct_number`='".$mat['material_bct_number']."' AND 
                            `unit_number`='".$unit['unit_number']."' AND 
                            `department_guid`='".$dept['department_guid']."'";

                foreach($pdo->query($sql_quan) AS $quan)
                {
                    echo "<td>".$quan['quantity']."</td>";
                }
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nested queries are expensive in performance; try reducing the number of queries by using JOINs

Comment: Further to Mark's comment, is it a large database? Are the tables you are querying indexed properly?

Comment: It is a larger database yes. And the table that has the quantity, the ID column and QUANTITY columns are both indexed, but that's all.

Comment: Your `LIMIT` clauses complicate converting this into a rather straightforward `JOIN`. You should also probably define what you mean by "fine". My initial guess is that your best bet is a compound index on the fields used in the innermost nested query's `WHERE` clause. Also, GUIDs are a bad idea for MySQL tables' primary/referenced keys unless absolutely necessary. One thing you might consider is use the outer queries to generate a `TEMPORARY` table you can then index and JOIN the final query against.

Comment: Would anyone have an example or be able to provide an example of how i'd do a JOIN on a query like that?

Comment: And what I mean by fine, is it's load time is near instantaneous. But as soon as I go to grab the QUANTITY as mentioned, load times go from 1 second to 30-40 seconds.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) in your queries.

When you do that, you know the relationship between tables that you're using in the query.

Next step, use [INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) in the fields that you're making match, and execute again you're queries.

Comment: So, if I'm matching the GUID between two tables and say, the UNIT_GUID between two tables - INDEX these columns?

Comment: The columns that seem to be slowing things up significantly is really just the QUANTITY column, which isn't relational to any other tables. It's only stored in that table.

Comment: @JordiePuchinger The `quantity` **column** should have no impact on your performance (unless it is used to hold large BLOBs); it is the conditions (and data types involved) that you are using in your WHERE clause.

Comment: @Uueerdo My QUANTITY column is DECIMAL(11,0). All of the GUID columns, were TEXT, but I am switching them to CHAR(40) - what are your thoughts on this? While I'm familiar with SQL, I'd consider myself a beginner at defining the data types.

Comment: @JordiePuchinger Any sort of string value is bad for use as keys, or join conditions, or even WHERE conditions where you are not trying to answer things like "users whose names are John" or "users whose names begin with J". _but CHAR is better than TEXT under these circumstances_